# How to override the default text in i18n files?

Tags: php, internationalization, symfony-1.4

I need to override some default text that are inherent to the i18n part of Symfony.

Those files are stored in `lib/vendor/symfony/lib/i18n/data`. They containts country name, month, metrics, etc ... for a given culture.

Here is a snapshot for `es.dat`:

```
a:19:{s:9:"Countries";a:278:{i:1;s:9:"Américas";i:2;s:6:"Caribe";i:3;s:17:"Europa meridional";i:5;s:11:"Suramérica";i:0;s:8:"Oceanía";i:9;
```

I need to change `portugués de Brasil` into `portugués (Brasil)`. Since it's not recommended to modifiy `.dat` file how can I override this value ?

Comment: Without the stacktrace, some part of your code, why not the .dat file, we won't be able to help you..

Comment: Even if the error log is big, you can still copy/paste it, can't you?

Comment: This problem is general. Anyone with the symfony 1.4 can reproduce this error. Anyway, one guy already told me that .dat files should not be changed. So, the question is how replace the text that is showed by default.

Comment: Your problem wasn't very clear. Where do you use the translation? To display a country list, a select to change language, ... ?

Comment: @j0k, in my particular case just a select to change the language. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's about the language selector, I guess you are using the `sfWidgetFormI18nChoiceLanguage`. So the simplest way is to create your own wdiget (which will be a c/p of the current one) to replace the value you want inside all choices. Create the new widget `lib/widget/myWidgetFormI18nChoiceLanguage.class.php`:

```
class myWidgetFormI18nChoiceLanguage extends sfWidgetFormChoice
{
  protected function configure($options = array(), $attributes = array())
  {
    parent::configure($options, $attributes);

    $this->addOption('culture');
    $this->addOption('languages');
    $this->addOption('add_empty', false);

    // populate choices with all languages
    $culture = isset($options['culture']) ? $options['culture'] : 'en';

    $languages = sfCultureInfo::getInstance($culture)->getLanguages(isset($options['languages']) ? $options['languages'] : null);

    $addEmpty = isset($options['add_empty']) ? $options['add_empty'] : false;
    if (false !== $addEmpty)
    {
      $languages = array_merge(array('' => true === $addEmpty ? '' : $addEmpty), $languages);
    }

    // change the language here based on the iso code
    $languages['pt_BR'] = 'portugués (Brasil)';

    $this->setOption('choices', $languages);
  }
}
```

And if you want to change the way you display the iso_code (when you use the i18n helper `format_language`), you can do the same. Create your own helper (like `/lib/helper/myi18NHelper.php`) with:

```
function format_language($language_iso, $culture = null)
{
  $c = sfCultureInfo::getInstance($culture === null ? sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getCulture() : $culture);
  $languages = $c->getLanguages();

  // change the language here based on the iso code
  $languages['pt_BR'] = 'portugués (Brasil)';

  return isset($languages[$language_iso]) ? $languages[$language_iso] : '';
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
<?php use_helper('myi18N') ?>

<?php echo format_language('pt_BR') ?>
```

**Edit:**

And if you want to use this new widget, update your form class and simply replace `sfWidgetFormI18nChoiceLanguage` by `myWidgetFormI18nChoiceLanguage`.

Comment: Thanks. If i create a new widget, where the file name is: myWidgetFormI18nChoiceLanguage.class.php and the class is:myWidgetFormI18nChoiceLanguage, how and where, can i call this widget that will override the default widget?

Comment: i need to update sfCoreAutoload config. now works well, thanks man. :)

Comment: well, i don't know, but i already deleted the cache and only works if i update the sfCoreAutoload